# perl - remove new line after comma within function definitions only

Tags: regex, perl

Regex command to remove new line after comma within function definitions only.

```
ChainCtrlUpdateHandler defaultUpdateHandlers[kVideoRouteNodeMax] =
{

    ChainCtrlUpdateMonitorRoute,
    ChainCtrlUpdateVideoOutRoute,
};

eErrorT ChainCtrlInitChains(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl,
    char* name,
    int instance,
    void* pOwner,
    )
 {
   ...
 }
```

OUTPUT DESIRED

```
ChainCtrlUpdateHandler defaultUpdateHandlers[kVideoRouteNodeMax] =
{

    ChainCtrlUpdateMonitorRoute,
    ChainCtrlUpdateVideoOutRoute,
};
eErrorT ChainCtrlInitChains(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl,char* name,int instance,void* pOwner)
{
   ....
}
```

NOTE
There are many function definitions in the .c file

MY CODE

```
open(my $FILE, "< chaincontroller.c") or die $!;
my @arr = <$FILE>;
foreach (@arr){
     $_ =~ s/,\n/,/;
     print $_;
  }
```

It removes ',\n' everywhere but i need it to be done only for functions definitions only.

Comment: Are there any function pointer arguments to these functions? (Which include `()`.)

Comment: NO. All of them in same format as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
perl -00 -ple 's/,\s*\n/,/gms if /\(/ .. /\)/' filename.txt
```

With a script :

```
perl -MO=Deparse -00 -ple 's/,\s*\n/,/gms if /\(/ .. /\)/' filename.txt
```

code :

```
BEGIN { $/ = ""; $\ = "\n\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    s/,\s*\n/,/gms if /\(/ .. /\)/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Comment: this code affects all lines. works similar to my code given above

Comment: i need to implement for functions definitions only